# not connect with default port on mongo db using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https

i am new in node js and i try to connect with mongodb with node js app but i am not able to connect Here is my code

```js
var mongo = require("mongodb");
var host="127.0.0.1";
//var port="27017";
var port=mongo.Connection.DEFAULT_PORT;
var db=new mongo.Db("nodejs-intoduction",new mongo.Server(host, port,{}));
db.open(function(error){
 console.log("We are connected.!" + host + ":" + port);
})
```

i am getting error like..

port=mongo.Connection.DEFAULT_PORT;

cannote read property 'DEFAULT_POST' of undefined

Comment: Shouldn't it be `require('mongodb').MongoClient`?

Comment: that give the error like mongo.server is not a function.. when i am trying this ...

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
 var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,

    // Connection url
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
    // Connect using MongoClient
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {


        db.close();
      });
    });
```

Comment: check your mongo server is running. use this command on cmd promt mongo.exe